# Why is my code showing Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c++, algorithm, segmentation-fault, flood-fill

My code is as follows. Its is giving segmentation fault. I have been debugging it but stuck! I can't find the problem. Can someone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char art[200][200];
char art2[200][200];
int n;

void solve(char a, int x, int y);

int main() {
    // ifstream fin("cowart.in");
    // ofstream fout("cowart.out");
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> art[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            art2[i][j] = art[i][j];
    int rh = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (art[i][j] == 'R' || art[i][j] == 'G' || art[i][j] == 'B') {
                rh++;
                solve(art[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    int rc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            art[i][j] = art2[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (art[i][j] == 'G')
                art[i][j] = 'R';
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (art[i][j] == 'R' || art[i][j] == 'B') {
                rc++;
                solve(art[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << rh << " " << rc << endl;
    // system("PAUSE");
    // fin.close();
    // fout.close();
    return 0;
}

void solve(char a, int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= n || y >= n)
        return;
    if (art[x][y] != a)
        return;
    art[x][y] == '.';
    if (x < n - 1)
        solve(a, x + 1, y);
    if (x > 0)
        solve(a, x - 1, y);
    if (y < n - 1)
        solve(a, x, y + 1);
    if (y > 0)
        solve(a, x, y - 1);
    return;
}
```

This code is the solution to: [USACO Problem 414](http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=414)

The test case i is showing Segmentation Fault is:

```
5
RRRBB
GGBBB
BBBRR
BBRRR
RRRRR
```

Output should be: `4 3`

Answer (score 1):

In the `solve()` function, notice this line?

```
art[x][y] == '.';
```

The code above tests if `art[x][y]` is equal to `'.'`, then throws the result away. It's legal C++, but does nothing useful. A smart compiler may give you a warning.

It's obviously meant to be assignment:

```
art[x][y] = '.';
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now and is giving AC :)

Answer (score 0):

The function solve() goes in infinite recursion, causing stack overflow.
Implement solve using non-recursive rather iterative method.
Implement 4-neighborhood problem in iterative way with loops and iterations